# listagg alternative in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have this base data:

```
    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        20 SMITH
        30 ALLEN
        30 WARD
        20 JONES
        30 MARTIN
        30 BLAKE
        10 CLARK
        20 SCOTT
        10 KING
        30 TURNER
        20 ADAMS
        30 JAMES
        20 FORD
        10 MILLER
```

I can achieve my desired output with listagg():

```
SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,MARTIN,TURNER,JAMES,WARD
```

But it is super slow. With my real data set it makes the query run time 35 seconds long instead of < 1 second.

Can I use `collect()` to speed this up? If so, how?

I have also heard of user-defined aggregate functions, but are these worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following user-defined function as suggested by Tom Kyte of [asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402) - performance is acceptable to me (although it will not work in Oracle 8). Can you try this ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg AS OBJECT
(
  g_string  VARCHAR2(32767),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
     RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER
);
/
SHOW ERRORS


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_string_agg(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := self.g_string || ',' || value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := RTRIM(LTRIM(SELF.g_string, ','), ',');
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || ',' || ctx2.g_string;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_agg (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg;
/
SHOW ERRORS
```

Application,

```
COLUMN employees FORMAT A50

SELECT deptno, string_agg(ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,MARTIN,TURNER,JAMES,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: It is hard to believe that a user-defined aggregate function would be faster than Oracle's built-in function. Have you got a benchmark for this?